# wit.ai handling words with or w/out diacritics as synonyms

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, facebook-messenger, wit.ai, facebook-messenger-bot

How to train the bot to recognize words with or without diacritics as synonyms, is this feature enabled? e.g. when I have a  word (camera): `foťák` I would like to be treated as synonym to `fotak`.

There are cases where diacritics really matters and semantic could be different, is such cases I should provide words in exact form. But my aim is easier training for words where semantic don't change.

**So, I would like to type words without diacritics and expect that same words with diacritics will be treated as synonyms. And only when diacritics matters I would provide words in such form to prevent confusion. Is that even possible?**

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is lemma
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(morphology)
https://pythonprogramming.net/lemmatizing-nltk-tutorial/

Comment: I hoped that wit.ai could do that for me :)